# Button in edit view in Unity

Tags: button, unity-game-engine

I'd like to know if there is a way to add a button in scene view when in edit mode in unity.
I'd like to choose an option from the gameobject menu and then deactivate it when the button on scene is clicked (before pressing run)

Is this possible please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking about Unity3D game engine. Well, by means of Editor scripts you can add a button in Editor mode. For example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;

public class LevelChunksAnalyser : MonoBehaviour {

    [MenuItem("Level Chunks/Update Metadata")]
    public static void UpdateLevelChunksMetadata()
    {
        Debug.Log("Yo");
    }
}
```